# ActiveMQ connect to existing queue at an address/port

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I'm supposed to send messages to an ActiveMQ queue named "IngestGenericJSONQueue" at address 10.7.1.10 at port 61616. I can create an ActiveMQConnectionFactory object, but then how do I look up an existing queue? So far, I've only managed to find the session.createQueue() function, but I'm not sure if this is used to create a connection to an existing queue, or only works to create a brand new queue. How can I connect to an existing activemq queue by name?

```
ConnectionFactory cFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://10.7.1.10:61616");
Connection connection = cFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

Destination queue = session.createQueue("IngestGenericJSONQueue");

System.out.println("queue connected");

MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
TextMessage m = session.createTextMessage();
m.setText(jsonStix.toString());

producer.send(m);

System.out.println("done");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveMQ creates Queues and Topics on demand so if there is no existing Queue of that name when you create the producer then a new Queue is created.  If the Queue already exists then the producer would send to that Queue.

You can use management tools like JMX or the Web console to explore a running Broker to see what Queues exist already.

Comment: It seems like even though I've started the ActiveMQ broker with a specific queue, when I use "createQueue" as the destination, the messages are not persisted.  When I send through the web console, however, they are persisted on restart, any thoughts on this Tim?

Comment: Thanks Tim, might be something with the Active MQ container I'm using though I have it setup with persisted storage.